# full calendar allow only 1 hour event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

i try to create an event Calendar with multiple users with full calendar (PHP, mysql). Is it possible to allow only to add 1 hour events? 
For example. User A can only add 1 hour Events. User B only 2 hour events?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

while adding events just check for the duration.

```
drop: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, ui) { 
        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            // this will provide you duration just compare it with your limit and process accordingly.
           copiedEventObject.duration
        },//drop function ends
```